# Javascript: style only first class element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these classes and inputs that are generated programmatically:

```html
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="1">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="2">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="3">
</div>
```

I would like to style only the first class. This is what I have done to achieve that, but with no luck.

```
 const timeInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputHolder");
  for (var i = 0; i < timeInputs.length; i++) {
    if (timeInputs[0]) {
      $("input").css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });
    }
  }
```

Comment: A pure CSS solution would be: `.inputHolder:nth-child(1) input {background-color: black; color: white;}`.

Comment: Why loop if you only want to change the first?

Comment: @epascarello as mentioned on my post, I get these programmatically generated. Sometimes, there is only one element with one input so if I do not loop, the changes only apply when there is more divs with their respective inputs.

Comment: Your text says "I would like to style only the first class" So again, why loop? Weird you are also mixing jQuery and DOM. That is not the best practice. `$(".inputHolder").eq(0).css({});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution in pure javascript.

```js
document.querySelector('.inputHolder .inputclss').classList.add('first')
```

```css
.first  {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="1">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="2">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="3">
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can simply use `querySelector()` which will return the first element that matches the selector.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for javascript here at all. Just use css. This works even if they are dynamically generated, and if there are 1 or more div elements.

```css
.inputHolder:nth-child(1) input {
  background-color: black;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="1">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="2">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inputHolder")[0];
var timeInputs = x.getElementsByClassName('inputclss')[0];
timeInputs.setAttribute('style', 'background: #000; color: #fff;');
```

```html
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="1">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="2">
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
    <input type="button" class="inputclss" value="3">
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but as I mentioned, the divs are generated programatically. Sometimes I get only one inputHold Element with one input, so getting the elements by the index of 0 in this case does not work, yet works when there is more elements

Comment: @Zeusox, This code must always work whether it is a single DIV element or more. It is important to load the code after the DIV elements have been generated

Answer (score -2):

Like i see u trying using native javascript and jQ too..
try to use full power of jQuery :)

```
$('.inputHolder input:first').css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });
```